# Select posts that match multiple category names, must match all categories listed

Tags: categories, wp-query, customization

I need to search for posts that belong to multiple categories, but they must match all categories listed, as in if I list category names 'japanese' and 'dessert' the matching posts need to be in both the 'japanese' and 'dessert categories.

Is there something like `category__and` for category names? I am using a wordpress multi instance and my category ID numbers vary between my test and production environments, hence I cannot use `category__and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you could grab category names ID using `get_the_category` function([Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)).

```
$names = {"japanese", "dessert"};
$categories = get_the_category();
if($categories){
 foreach($categories as $category){
  if( in_array($category->cat_name, $names) ) array_push($ids, $category->term_id);
 }
}
```

Comment: That was basically what I did. I got the ID #'s with a query and then used category__and with an array of variables